# Is it possible to run sntp as daemon?

Tags: ntp

I see that sntp just prints the time( time offset and error bound of the system clock relative to the server clock ), but it doesn't update system time(to be synchronized with server time) as it does ntp... 
my questions are

```
    1.Is it possible to run sntp as daemon ?
    2.beside sntp are there other light versions of ntp, which I can use to synchronize time?
```